# How to close IPython Notebook properly?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter

How to close IPython Notebook properly?

Currently, I just close the browser tabs and then use `Ctrl+C` in the terminal.
Unfortunately, neither `exit()` nor ticking `Kill kernel upon exit` does help (they do kill the kernel they but don't exit the iPython).

Comment: The PID of a particular kernel (open at a particular port) can be seen with `ps -ax` or `top`. Thus kernels can be selectively stopped with [administrative privilege] to terminate that particular process: # kill PID-of-k-i
This allows no internal shutdown procedures for the kernel, but neither do the forced Ctl-C type.... Does anyone know if this is planned for jupyter?

Answer (score 149, accepted):

There isn't currently a better way to do it than Ctrl+C in the terminal.

We're thinking about how to have an explicit shutdown, but there's some tension between the notebook as a single-user application, where the user is free to stop it, and as a multi-user server, where only an admin should be able to stop it. We haven't quite worked out how to handle the differences yet.

(For future readers, this is the situation with 0.12 released and 0.13 in development.)

**Update December 2017**

The IPython Notebook has become the Jupyter Notebook. A recent version has added a `jupyter notebook stop` shell command which will shut down a server running on that system. You can pass the port number at the command line if it's not the default port 8888.

You can also use [nbmanager](https://github.com/jupyter/nbmanager), a desktop application which can show running servers and shut them down.

Finally, we are working on adding:

- A config option to automatically shut down the server if you don't use it for a specified time.
- A button in the user interface to shut the server down. (We know it's a bit crazy that it has taken this long. Changing UI is controversial.)

Comment: Maybe then just offer an option to allow for explicit kill (via a button in the menu?) or not in the config file and commandline? So that people who want the server to always run can just set up the correct config.

Comment: It has been a few years, has this situation changed at all? Is Ctrl+C still the only sure way to shut down an iPython Notebook server?

Comment: There still isn't a way to shut it down from inside the notebook UI, but I wrote [nbmanager](https://github.com/takluyver/nbmanager), a tool that can list and kill notebook servers and kernels.

Comment: So I assume using `jupyter notebook &` is a bad idea since `Ctrl`+`C` does not apply for this situation

Comment: I tried this, but there is no way to type anything into the console that is running the Jupyter Notebook process other than ctrl+C. I tried opening a new powershell/command prompt and typing jupyter notebook stop from there, but it didn't work.

Comment: @julianhatwell The `jupyter notbook stop` should be typed into a different console

Answer (score 32):

I think accepted answer outdated and is not valid anymore.

You can terminate jupyter notebook from web interface on file menü item.

[image]

When you move Mouse cursor on "close and halt", you will see following explanation.

[image]

And when you click "close and halt", you will see following message on terminal screen.

[image]

Comment: To clarify, this stops the *kernel*, the process which runs your Python code. It doesn't stop the *notebook server*, which makes the notebook interfaces, deals with loading and saving files, etc.

Comment: I do not have this drop down menu from my interface, I copy and paste the URL to chrome browser.

Answer (score 29):

If you run jupyter in the background like me:

```
jupyter notebook &> /dev/null &
```

Then to exit jupyter completely, instead of Ctl-C, make an alias command:

```
echo 'alias quitjupyter="kill $(pgrep jupyter)"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Restart your terminal. Kill all jupyter instances:

```
quitjupyter
```

Note: use double quotes inside of single quotes as shown above.  The other way around will evaluate the expression before writing it to your .bashrc (you want to write the command itself not 'kill 1430' or whatever process number may be associated with a current jupyter instance).  Of course you can use any alias you wish.  I actually use 'qjup':

```
echo 'alias qjup="kill $(pgrep jupyter)"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Restart your terminal. Kill all jupyter instances:

```
qjup
```

Comment: The `kill $(pgrep jupyter)` by itself is excellent. I was running `jupyter notebook` from a remote terminal that crashed -- CTRL+C approach is then impossible upon logging back in. Saving the nuclear option of restarting remote, this is great.

Comment: Why not just `pkill jupyter`? `pkill` is `pgreb`, but for killing processes.

Comment: What does the dollar sign do? I get a correct answer from
ps | grep jupyter
but a null response from
pgrep jupyter
Can anyone explain the difference?  GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin18) macos 10.14.6

Comment: At least on BSD/MacOS, I needed "pgrep -f jupyter", so the match checks the full argument list, not just the process name.

Answer (score 25):

First step is to save all open notebooks. And then think about shutting down your running Jupyter Notebook. You can use this simple command:

```
$ jupyter notebook stop 
Shutting down server on port 8888 ...
```

Which also takes the port number as argument and you can shut down the jupyter notebook gracefully.

For eg:

```
jupyter notebook stop 8889 
Shutting down server on port 8889 ...
```

Additionally to know your current jupyter instance running, check below command:

```
shell> jupyter notebook list 
Currently running servers:
http://localhost:8888/?token=ef12021898c435f865ec706de98632 :: /Users/username/jupyter-notebooks [/code]
```

Comment: That was a typo, thankyou for bringing it up. Rectified.

Answer (score 16):

These commands worked for me:

```
jupyter notebook list # shows the running notebooks and their port-numbers
                      # (for instance: 8080)
lsof -n -i4TCP:[port-number] # shows PID.
kill -9 [PID] # kill the process.
```

This answer was adapted from [here](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2844#issuecomment-385882596).

Answer (score 5):

Try killing the pythonw process from the Task Manager (if Windows) if nothing else works.

Answer (score 5):

```
Linux (Ubuntu 14.04)
```

As mentioned, try to kill ipython notebook processes properly by first going to the "running" tab in your ipynb/jupyter browser session, and then check open terminals on your console and shut down with ctrl-c. The latter should be avoided if possible.

If you run an `ipython notebook list` and continue to see running ipython servers at different ports, make note of which ports the existing notebooks are being served to. Then shut down your TCP ports:

```
fuser -k 'port#'/tcp
```

I'm not sure if there are other risks involved with doing this. If so, let me know.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, I believe there's a cleaner way than killing the process(es) using kill or task manager.

In the Jupyter Notebook Dashboard (the browser interface you see when you first launch 'jupyter notebook'), browse to the location of notebook files you have closed in the browser, but whose kernels may still be running.

iPython Notebook files appear with a book icon, shown in green if it has a running kernel, or gray if the kernel is not running.

Just select the tick box next to the running file, then click on the Shutdown button that appears above it.

This will properly shut down the kernel associated with that specific notebook.

Answer (score 3):

**Option 1**

Open a different console and run

```
jupyter notebook stop [PORT]
```

The default [PORT] is 8888, so, assuming that Jupyter Notebooks is running on port 8888, just run

```
jupyter notebook stop
```

If it is on port 9000, then

```
jupyter notebook stop 9000
```

---

**Option 2** ([Source](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2844#issuecomment-505763830))

1. Check runtime folder location

   ```
   jupyter --paths
   ```
2. Remove all files in the runtime folder

   ```
   rm -r [RUNTIME FOLDER PATH]/*
   ```
3. Use `top` to find any Jupyter Notebook running processes left and if so kill their PID.

   ```
   top | grep jupyter &
   kill [PID]
   ```

One can [boilt it down](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2844#issuecomment-517982785) to

```
TARGET_PORT=8888
kill -9 $(lsof -n -i4TCP:$TARGET_PORT | cut -f 2 -d " ")
```

---

**Option 3**

As a last resort, what Hary shares [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57851346/7109869) can also be helpful

```
sudo pkill -1 -f python
```

---

**Note**: If one wants to launch one's Notebook on a specific IP/Port

```
jupyter notebook --ip=[ADD_IP] --port=[ADD_PORT] --allow-root &
```

Answer (score 2):

**Environment**

---

My OS is Ubuntu 16.04 and jupyter is 4.3.0.

**Method**

---

First, i logged out jupyter at its homepage on browser(the logout button is at top-right)

Second, type in `Ctrl + C` in your terminal and it shows:

> [I 15:59:48.407 NotebookApp]interrupted Serving notebooks from local
>   directory: /home/Username 0 active kernels
>
> The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
>   http://localhost:8888/?token=a572c743dfb73eee28538f9a181bf4d9ad412b19fbb96c82
>
> Shutdown this notebook server (y/[n])?

Last step, type in `y` within 5 sec, and if it shows:

> [C 15:59:50.407 NotebookApp] Shutdown confirmed
>   [I 15:59:50.408
>   NotebookApp] Shutting down kernels

Congrats! You close your jupyter successfully.

Answer (score 2):

The best way now is to use the "Quit" button that is just to the left of the "Logout" button. I have to admit that I do not understand the utility of the Logout button. However, I am glad that they have added the exceedingly useful Quit button.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on mac and using Jupyter lab you can do the following in terminal

```
jupyter list
```

Above will give you all the running servers. Once you get to know the post just use jupyter lab stop. For example if the server was running on 8888 just execute

```
jupyter lab stop 8888
```

Answer (score 0):

In the browser session you can also go to `Kernel` and then click `Restart and Clear Output`.

Answer (score 0):

I am copy pasting from the Jupyter/IPython Notebook Quick Start
Guide Documentation, released on Feb 13, 2018.
http://jupyter-notebook-beginner-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/execute.html

1.3.3 Close a notebook: kernel shut down
When a notebook is opened, its “computational engine” (called the kernel) is automatically started. Closing the
notebook browser tab, will not shut down the kernel, instead the kernel will keep running until is explicitly shut down.
To shut down a kernel, go to the associated notebook and click on menu File -> Close and Halt. Alternatively, the
Notebook Dashboard has a tab named Running that shows all the running notebooks (i.e. kernels) and allows shutting
them down (by clicking on a Shutdown button).

**Summary: First close and halt the notebooks running.**

1.3.2 Shut down the Jupyter Notebook App
Closing the browser (or the tab) will not close the Jupyter Notebook App. To completely shut it down you need to
close the associated terminal.
In more detail, the Jupyter Notebook App is a server that appears in your browser at a default address
(http://localhost:8888). Closing the browser will not shut down the server. You can reopen the previous address
and the Jupyter Notebook App will be redisplayed.
You can run many copies of the Jupyter Notebook App and they will show up at a similar address (only the number
after “:”, which is the port, will increment for each new copy). Since with a single Jupyter Notebook App you can
already open many notebooks, we do not recommend running multiple copies of Jupyter 
Notebook App.

**Summary: Second, quit the terminal from which you fired Jupyter.**

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 - On shell just do control+z (control+c)
Step 2 _ close the web browser

Answer (score 0):

To kill all `jupyter-notebook` and `jupyter-lab`, open terminal and just kill all `jupyter` that running in background by giving

`pkill jupyter`