# Run Jupyter Notebook in the Background on Docker

Tags: terminal, docker, sh, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to run a jupyter notebook in the background without printing anything to the console. I found this solution in a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10162707/how-to-close-ipython-notebook-properly/32745046#32745046) for bash:

`jupyter notebook &> /dev/null &`

But I am running jupyter in a docker container and want it to start in the background via `CMD`. How can I do the same in sh?

Comment: So far I don't know a way and the docs don't see to indicate that is possible by default. Your solution should work, though, adding this line on the CMD line in Docker.

Comment: thanks @Ivan the problem is that docker runs CMD commands in sh, not in bash and it doesn't seem to have the same effect in sh.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got it to work using the setup from: 
 https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/tree/master/minimal-notebook

the trick was to install tini and put the following code into a start-notebook.sh script:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec jupyter notebook &> /dev/null &
```

this is than added to the path with:
`COPY start-notebook.sh /usr/local/bin/` and 
`RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/start-notebook.sh`

Then I could set `CMD ["start-notebook.sh"]` to start up the container with jupyter running in the background on start.

Comment: Can you explain what does the `&> /dev/null &` do? especially the two `&` symbols?

Comment: It ensures that the logs are not printed to `stdout` but redirected into `dev/null` and that the terminal doesn't get blocked with Jupiter but that jupyter is just fired off as a background process. Just try it out.

Comment: the `&>` is a newer bash-ism, "functional as of Bash 4" [as per the docs](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html), which redirects _both_ stderr and stdout. Alternatively, and more traditionally: `jupyter notebook > /dev/null  2>&1` , or, preferably, `jupyter notebook >> /path/to/logfile.log  2>&1` (the last, trailing `&` just runs the entire command in the background).

Comment: @MrLoh What did you do to gain access to the notebook in the browser? with token or pass - what/how did you do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can do that, executing the below command

```sh
jupyter notebook --allow-root &> /dev/null &
```

You might see the warning that jupyter command needs `--allow-root` option if you execute `jupyter notebook` command **as a root** in a docker container.