# Running Jupyter Notebook in the background on remote server, get output

Tags: ssh, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to run a Jupyter Notebook in the background. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34865097/run-jupyter-notebook-in-the-background-on-docker) that included the command

```
jupyter notebook &> /dev/null &
```

which worked on my local machine. However, I have two problems:

1. I need a token in order to be able to access my notebooks in a browser window. However, with the above command, there is no output into the Terminal window except for the process ID, and therefore I could not access my notebooks.
2. I also need to run the notebook in the background on a remote machine. I `ssh` into the remote machine, and then run `jupyter notebook --no-browser`. However, once I close my laptop, the notebook process is killed in my local Terminal window, as well as the `ssh`.

I was able to crudely circumvent the above problems by running the normal

```
jupyter notebook --no-browser
```

in the remote server, and then killing the `ssh` to the remote server. My question boils down to the following two sub-questions:

1. Is there any way of doing this besides closing the `ssh`? I guess this isn't really the biggest problem, but it seems very hacky to simply kill the ssh instead of some more elegant or more effective solution.
2. How would I achieve the same thing on my local machine? I need to run the Jupyter Notebook in the background while also somehow getting the output. Can I direct the output into another file or read it somewhere else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Generate a *password* for your Jupyter Notebook server so that you don't need to enter it via *token* (which will be changed each time you restart the server).
2. Run your Jupyter Notebook server in a *screen* or a *tmux*, thus each time you close the connection with the remote server, you just **detach** from the screen. It will keep on running in your remote server. Next time you want to access to it, just tap in `screen -r` to attach the screen after you `ssh` to the remote server.

Answer (score 1):

Run the Jupyter notebook on tmux with no-browser option. And take the browser when you want it. To keep the running session like variables and all, you can make use of nbconvert in Jupyter, use the command : `jupyter nbconvert --to notebook --execute --inplace mynotebook.ipynb`  to get the outputs on Jupyter notebook when you open it on browser after detaching several times.