# cannot quit jupyter notebook server running

Tags: python, server, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I am using Jupyter Notebook for a project. Since I ssh into a linux cluster at work I use

```
ssh -Y -L 8000:localhost:8888 user@host
```

Then I start the notebook with `jupyter notebook --no-browser &` so that I can continue using the terminal. Then on my local machine I open to `localhost:8000` and go about my work.

My problem is that I forgot several times to close the server by foregrounding the process and killing it with `Ctrl-C`. Instead I just logged out of the ssh session. Now when I run `jupyter notebook list` I get

```
Currently running servers:
http://localhost:8934/ :: /export/home/jbalsells
http://localhost:8870/ :: /export/home/jbalsells
http://localhost:8892/ :: /export/home/jbalsells
http://localhost:8891/ :: /export/home/jbalsells
http://localhost:8890/ :: /export/home/jbalsells
http://localhost:8889/ :: /export/home/jbalsells
http://localhost:8888/ :: /export/home/jbalsells
```

I obviously do not want all of these servers running on my work's machine, but I do not know how to close them!

When I run ps I get nothing:

```
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
12678 pts/13   00:00:00 bash
22584 pts/13   00:00:00 ps
```

I have Jupyter 4.1.0 installed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to close IPython Notebook properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10162707/how-to-close-ipython-notebook-properly)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

So I found a solution.

Since `jupyter notebook list` tells you which ports the notebook servers are running on I looked for the PIDs using `netstat -tulpn` I got the information from http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/what-process-has-open-linux-port/

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       
PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8649            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
-                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:139             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
-                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:33483           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
-                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5901            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
39125/Xvnc
```

Without looking too hard I was able to find the ports I knew to look for from `jupyter notebook list` and the processes running them (you could use `grep` if it were too hard to find them). Then I killed them with
`kill 8337` (or whatever number was associated).

Comment: Suggestions for windows? :)

Comment: It looks like in a recent update 'jupyter notebook stop 8888' will work to stop the notebook running on port 8888.

Answer (score 17):

Windows Systems commands on Command Prompt

Be careful to save all the changes made in your notebooks prior to kill the jupyter notebook server process.

**i) find the port number used by jupyter notebook server**

```
jupyter notebook list
```

ex.)

```
jupyter notebook list
Currently running servers:
http://127.0.0.1:8888/ :: D:\kimkk\Documents\JupyterNotebook
```

**ii) find process ids that use the found port number of jupyter notebook**

```
netstat -ano | find "found portnumber"
```

ex.)

```
netstat -ano | find "8888"

  TCP    127.0.0.1:8888         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       24140
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8888         127.0.0.1:55588        ESTABLISHED     24140
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8888         127.0.0.1:55612        ESTABLISHED     24140
  TCP    127.0.0.1:55588        127.0.0.1:8888         ESTABLISHED     6492
  TCP    127.0.0.1:55612        127.0.0.1:8888         ESTABLISHED     6492
```

- find rows with second column value equals to "8888". In above example first, second, and third rows are target rows. In those rows, you can find PID in the last column (ex. 24140).

**iii) kill jupyter notebook process with found PID**

```
taskkill /PID found_PID /F
```

ex.)

```
taskkill /PID 24140 /F
```

- /F means forcely kill the process.

FYI, Jupyter notebook from version 5.1 supports stop command as follows:

```
jupyter notebook stop 8888
```

refer to https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/1950

Comment: please edit to put "jupyter notebook stop 8888" at the top ... it should be the standard answer now

Answer (score 14):

Use the following command to stop Jupyter notebook running on port 8888:

```
fuser -k 8888/tcp
```

Answer (score 13):

This might help:

1. run `jupyter notebook list` to get the port number jupyter uses.
2. run `lsof -n -i4TCP:[port-number]` to get PID.
   The PID is the second field in the output.
3. run `kill -9 [PID]` to kill this process.

Answer (score 6):

I ran into the same issue and followed the solution posted above. Just wanted to clearify the solution a little bit.

```
netstat -tulpn
```

will list all the active connections.

```
tcp    0   0 0.0.0.0:8888  0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN      19524/python
```

you will need the PID "19524" in this case. you can even use the following to get the PID of the port you are trying to shut down

```
fuser 8888/tcp
```

this will give you 19524 as well.

```
kill 19524
```

will shut down the port

Comment: You method is much more clean and helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Section 3.3 should be applicable to this.
http://jupyter-notebook-beginner-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/execute.html

> When a notebook is opened, its “computational engine” (called the kernel) is automatically started. Closing the notebook browser tab, will not shut down the kernel, instead the kernel will keep running until is explicitly shut down.
>
> To shut down a kernel, go to the associated notebook and click on menu File -> Close and Halt. Alternatively, the Notebook Dashboard has a tab named Running that shows all the running notebooks (i.e. kernels) and allows shutting them down (by clicking on a Shutdown button).

Comment: I am not trying to close the notebook, but the server (Called the Jupyter Notebook App)

Comment: @Joalito sorry I misunderstood.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a bash script that will kill ALL active Jupyter notebook servers at one go, based on the answers given by @Joalito and @Hongsoog:

```
#!/bin/bash
jupyter notebook list | {
  while IFS= read -r line
  do
    port=`echo "$line" | grep -o -P '(?<=localhost:).*(?=/ :)'`
    echo "killing jn in port $port"
    if [ -z "$port" ]
    then
      netstat -tulpn | grep "$port" | grep -o -P '(?<=LISTEN      ).*(?=/py)' | xargs kill -15
    fi
  done
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On your notebook the welcoming page is named "Files" and you can see "Running" next to it. There is where you would want to shutdown and see the running notebooks

Comment: This does not answer the question... see the comment on the previous answer.

Comment: Oh my bad, I misunderstood

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was

1. `jupyter notebook list`, which in my case returned:

```
http://localhost:8889/?token=77d01d687da830b74eba946060660d :: /gpfs/blah/
http://localhost:8889/?token=1243162854ee3648e3154b26643794 :: /ifs/hello/world/
```

2. `netstat -tulpn | grep "8888"`, which in my case returned:

```
tcp        7      0 127.0.0.1:8888          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      17602/python3.9
```

And I found the PID in the last column: `17602`.

3. `kill -9 17602`, which freed up the port.

Answer (score 0):

Now, there is a native jupyter command to stop the jupyter server:

for Jupyter Notebook:

```
jupyter notebook stop [port]
```

for JupyterLab:

```
jupyter server stop [port]
```