# How to shutdown jupyter notebook app (server) without using ctrl-c?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I run a jupyter notebook in the background on a Mac using

```
>jupyter notebook &
```

Because it is running in the background I can't use use `ctrl-c` to kill it. Furthermore no processes seem to have the name `jupyter` in the activity monitor.

This github issue suggests that this no way to do it from the browser: https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/1530
however it says it should be possible to do from the command line using `jupyter notebook stop <portno>` but that does not seem to work for me.

How do I shutdown the jupyter server (ideally without having to search for the `pid` and then invoking `kill`)?

Comment: In a terminal use `ps aux` to view all running processes. If it is not in this list, it is not running. Then use `kill` with the PID of the process.

Comment: I can't even find the pid because no processes are named jupyter as mentionned. But in any case, I would like a more elegant way if possible.

Comment: If there are no processes named jupyter, then jupyter isn't running. I don't know what sort of answer you were expecting, in terms of "more elegant".

Comment: It is most definitely running because I can still access from the browser.

Comment: do `ps aux | grep jupyter` does it return anything?

Comment: right, interestingly the process isn't named jupyter but it can be found using `ps` because the launch command contains jupyter.

Comment: What do you mean? Do you mean it's not showing up as "process name" in MacOS Activity Monitor? Don't use that. Use *the shell*.

Comment: That is what I meant indeed.

Comment: Also, you can always use `jobs` to see running background jobs. Then, use `fg` to put the job back in the *foreground*, and then you can use ctrl-c. If there are more than one, there will be a number, e.g. `[2]+  Running                 jupyter notebook &` then you use the number, e.g. `fg 2`, or just kill it directly `kill %2`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thank you! That is the best answer for me so far.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Starting from jupyter notebook version 5.1.0**, the command

```
jupyter notebook stop <port number>
```

should shutdown the notebook server. If you don't enter a port, it defaults to `8888` as that is the default. To know on which ports the servers are currently running, you can do

```
jupyter notebook list
```

**With jupyter notebook version 5.0**, if it is running in the background of your terminal a solution is to do as @juanpa.arrivillaga wrote in the comments:

```
jobs
```

to see the jobs running in the background
if there is only one and it is the jupyter notebook then

```
fg
```

will bring it back to the foreground at which point you can kill it with `ctrl-c`. And if there are many processes in the background, for example, `jobs` returns

> [1]   Running                 firefox &
>
> [2]   Running                 jupyter notebook &
>
> [3]   Running                 python calc.py &

then `fg 2` brings the wanted process back to the foreground to be able to kill it with `ctrl-c`, or in one step `kill %2`.

Comment: For JupyterLab: `jupyter lab stop [port]`

Answer (score 3):

In a terminal you could run

`pkill -f -1 jupyter*`

Or I have found this to work when all else fails

`sudo pkill -1 -f python`

Answer (score 0):

Use `kill -9` or `kill -2` command. To find id of your process use `ps aux`.

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue when running in the background on an EC2, rebooting fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

On mac terminal after running
`jupyter notebook`
it says

> Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).

I've tried it - it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

To stop jupyter lab for which
`jupyter notebook list` will give nothing it can be done in two steps
1)

```
kill $(pgrep jupyter)
```

if when start a new instance you are getting

```
Jupyter command "jupyter-lab" not found.
```

just reactivate enviroment on which you are starting jupyter lab e.g.
2)

```
conda activate base
```