# How do I change the default browser used by Jupyter Notebook in Windows?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, anaconda, jupyter

I'm on a Windows machine without admin right and I would like to run Jupyter on Chrome, while the default browser is another.

I have a local installation of the Anaconda distribution and my first option to start Jupyter would be through the Anaconda Navigator, but maybe I have to do something else. Because it is a local installation the command line `jupyter notebook` produces no results.

When I paste the url address I have in the default browser (something like `http://localhost:8892/notebooks/Home/Exercices/Testing1.ipynb`) the chrome page asks me for a password or token. I have no password and I do not know what a token is.

Is there a way to change the browser of the Anaconda Navigator? or how can I start Jupyter with Chrome?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Thanks to @Darthbith and this post [How to change the default browser used by the ipython/jupyter notebook in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35229604/how-to-change-the-default-browser-used-by-the-ipython-jupyter-notebook-in-linux?rq=1) I was able to figure it out:

Step 1: To open Anaconda Prompt from the Start Menu and type

```bash
# for old notebook and JupyterLab < 3.0, or
jupyter notebook --generate-config
# for new nbclassic and JupyterLab >= 3.0
jupyter server --generate-config
```

This will generate the file `~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py` (or `jupyter_server_config.py` for nbclassic/new JupyterLab)

Step 2: Edit this file and change the following line (chrome is also in a local installation)

```py
# for old notebook and JupyterLab < 3.0
c.NotebookApp.browser = u'C:/Home/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s'
# OR for new nbclassic and JupyterLab >= 3.0
c.ServerApp.browser = u'C:/Home/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s'
```

Comment: what is `%s` for here? on Linux things are much simplier

Comment: Just out of curiosity, `jupyter_notebook_config.py` is a Python file yet the variable `c` has never been defined and still be used. How could that work?

Comment: Kindly remind those friends who googled this post, you have to quote your browser command if there is space in the path to make it work. e.g., `c.NotebookApp.browser = '"C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe" %s'`

Comment: This worked for me with Chrome from PortableApps too.

Comment: Don't forget to remove # sign at the beginning. I forgot that :D

Comment: This is not working anymore as of 2021/03/17 since chrome.exe is no more installed here C:/Home/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe. It is installed instead here: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Firefox.exe. But if you put this  c.NotebookApp.browser = u'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Firefox.exe %s' in the config file it does not work. (Here I want to make it Firefox but the same is true for google.)

Comment: @G.T. The solution is for an installation without admin rights. You will end in the location C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\ if you have admin rights. My guess is that the solution will still be valid for some years

Comment: I tried it unsuccessfully as administator in Win10Pro, as follows: c.NotebookApp.browser = u'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe %s'. The solution proposed below by Abhirup Das DID work for me. I do not know why, but I thought you more technically astute folk might want this info.

Answer (score 61):

In Windows, write in cmd/ Anaconda Prompt:

```
jupyter notebook --generate-config
```

The jupyter_notebook_config.py file generated is situated in "C:\Users\YourName\.jupyter\" folder.

Open it using a text editor and change `#c.NotebookApp.browser = ''` to

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.register('chrome', None, webbrowser.GenericBrowser(u'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe'))
c.NotebookApp.browser = 'chrome'
```

and save the file.

Now execute the jupyter-notebook command and the set browser will be used.

Comment: This is what definitely works in windows. As an example see those three lines for me: import webbrowser
webbrowser.register('Mozila', None, webbrowser.GenericBrowser(u'C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\Firefox.exe'))
c.NotebookApp.browser = 'Mozila'    Here I wanted to make mozila my defaut browser for Jupyter.

Comment: Thanks, this is the only solution which worked for me on a non-admin account. For reference, I used MS Edge Chromium:
`import webbrowser`
`webbrowser.register('edge', None, webbrowser.GenericBrowser(u'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedge.exe'))`
`c.NotebookApp.browser = 'edge'`

Comment: I've tried everything else posted in this community but never works. Something like u' +path + s% never works for me. But your code works like a charm! Thank you! @Abhirup Das

Comment: I too tried other solutions, but only yours worked for me.  Thank you so much!

Comment: I used `c.ServerApp.browser` and it works for JupyterLab 3.3.2, and doesn't work for Jupyter Notebook 6.4.8. But that's okay for now.

Comment: If you use multiple profiles in chrome, you can select it with:
`webbrowser.register('chrome', None, webbrowser.get("C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe  --profile-directory=\"Profile 2\" %s"))`

Answer (score 12):

I don't know the precise details for Windows, but this is how to set the default browser on a Mac:

```
jupyter notebook --generate-config
```

This creates a file jupyter_notebook_config.py in ~/.jupyter.  Edit the line

```
#c.NotebookApp.browser = ''
```

On a Mac I set it to:

```
c.NotebookApp.browser = u'open -a /Applications/Gooogle\ Chrome.app %s'
```

You just need to figure out how to point it to Chrome on Windows.

Comment: Oh, good answer! I forgot about the config file. I'm not sure how it works on Windows either. Note that the `jupyter notebook --generate-config` command should be run from the Anaconda Prompt on Windows

Comment: Just make a little correction for Mac setup:
c.NotebookApp.browser = u'open -a /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app %s'

Comment: Note the three o's in Gooogle - change it to Google; Also for Jupyter Lab it will be `c.ServerApp.browser = u'open -a /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app %s'`

Answer (score 10):

As far as I know, there's no way to change the default browser that opens. However, you can find the token for the Notebook server by opening Anaconda Prompt from the Start Menu and typing

```
jupyter notebook list
```

This will give you a URL with the token that you can copy/paste into any other browser. The output of the `list` command looks like

```
Currently running servers:
http://localhost:8888/?token=41429d3dcf554d0dde69498aac0950654a590664ba02b3cd :: /path/to/home/folder
```

So you can either type `http://localhost:8888` into the browser and then copy/paste the token into the field, or just copy/paste the whole URL with the token.

Comment: Thanks, that enable me to see the running servers and open any of them in another browser. Becuase I see 5 servers, I wonder how I should stop them

Comment: It was not so obvious how to close a server. Here a question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10162707/how-to-close-ipython-notebook-properly and a request https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/pull/3004

Answer (score 9):

The following also works for me. I give it a full path to chrome, plus `%s` at the end.

```
jupyter notebook --browser='C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s'
```

If chrome is in the PATH environment variable, the following might work too.

```
jupyter notebook --browser=chrome
```

Comment: Thanks this works on linux, the %s at the end at the full path is mandatory, else this error pops up:
'No web browser found: could not locate runnable browser.'

Comment: Specifically for Chrome I had to specify `--browser=google-chrome` on my Ubuntu system

Answer (score 9):

You don't need to change anything in the jupyter_notebook_config file. Check whether your default web browser (if it's Chrome) or reset and again choose as a web browser (Chrome for me) as a default browser.

Comment: This worked for me too in Windows 10. You open your preferred browser and it will prompt you to make it a default browser if its not, once you set it as default browser, then Anaconda Navigator will open automatically in that browser. Another way to set the default browser in Windows is to go to "Settings >  Apps > Default apps > Web browser > select the preferred browser by clicking it"

Comment: nice alternative to the config based examples.

Answer (score 7):

I'd like to offer a little more information about what to put in your jupyter_notebook_config.py file than is included in any of the other answers. jupyter is using python's [webrowser](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/webbrowser.html) module to launch the browser by passing the value for c.NotebookApp.browser to the [webbrowser.get(using=None)](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/webbrowser.html#webbrowser.get) function. If no value is specified, the function selects the user's default browser. If you do specify a value here, it can be interpreted in one of two ways, depending on whether or not the value you specified ends with the characters `%s`.

If the string does not contain the characters `%s`
it is interpreted as a browser name and the module checks if it has a browser registered with that name (see the python documentation for which browsers are registered by default). This is why Abhirup Das's answer works, first the webbrowser module is imported

`import webbrowser`

the chrome browser is registered with the module

`webbrowser.register('chrome', None, webbrowser.GenericBrowser(u'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe'))`

and finally, the jupyter server is fed the browser name

`c.NotebookApp.browser = 'chrome'`

This browser registration does not persist, so the process must be repeated every time the server is launched.

Alternatively, if the string does contain the characters `%s`, it is interpreted as a literal browser command. Since this question is about how to run the browser ***on Windows***, the browser command will probably contain backslashes. The backslash is used in python string literals to escape any characters that otherwise have any special meaning (e.g., to include a quote or double quote inside the string literal). Any backslashes in the browser command need to be be escaped or replaced. The easiest way is to replace the backslashes in the command with foward slashes, e.g.,

`'C:/Home/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s'`

rather than

`'C:\Home\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe %s'`

I for the life of me couldn't get unicode/raw string commands or commands where I escaped each backslash with an extra backslash to work, so replacing the backslashes with forward slashes may be the only option. I verified that the strings I tried all worked in python, so the only way to be sure would be to look at the jupyter source code.

Anyway, since registering a browser with the module does not persist, if your browser isn't already registered by default, it is probably best to use a literal browser command with the backslashes replaced with forward slashes.

Comment: Excellent and thorough explanation of the topic.

Comment: The "%s" part at the end is necessary if you want to pass some options to the command.
I wanted to start my non-default browser (chromium) in fullscreen mode.

    `c.ServerApp.browser = '/usr/bin/chromium-browser --start-fullscreen %s'`

Answer (score 5):

On Mac this works:

1) Generate a config file from within your environment:

```sh
jupyter notebook --generate-config
```

This will place `jupyter_notebook_config.py` in `~/.jupyter`.

2) Modify the following line in `jupyter_notebook_config.py`:

```py
c.NotebookApp.browser = 'open -a /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app %s'
```

Answer (score 5):

For linux users:

First generate config file using:
`jupyter notebook --generate-config`

Then open the generated file and look for `#c.NotebookApp.browser = ''`

Edit it to : `c.NotebookApp.browser = '/bin/brave %s'`

Replace **/bin/brave** with whatever your browser executable location is.

Comment: In my case, it was c.NotebookApp.browser = '/bin/brave-browser %s'

Answer (score 5):

There is a much simpler way than typing commands in the command window, you can use the Windows file explorer!
Simply navigate to the following path `C:\Users\**YourUser**\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime\`, as below:

[image: Path containing the html files]

There, among other files, you will see the corresponding `.html` files of your jupyter jobs. You can right-click on any `.html` file, select "Open As" as then select other application (as shown on the image below - apologies my default language is in Spanish).

[image: Select list of possible applications to open the file]

From here, you can select the most suitable navigator for you. In my case I am using Firefox, but you can choose Chrome or whatever (as shown below). **Make sure to click the "Use always this application to open .html files" checkbox to set Chrome as the default navigator.**

[image: Select the most appropriate navigator and set it as default]

From now on, Jupyter Notebooks will always open in Chrome.

Answer (score 3):

The explanations above didn't work for me, I guess, I mistyped something. Actually it was easier for me to change default browser to Chrome and then Jupiter automatically starts in Chrome after next launch. (Search Windows - change default browser).

Answer (score 3):

Jupyter looks for the `BROWSER` environment variable when choosing which browser to launch.

I recommend setting `BROWSER` over configuring Jupyter specifically, because setting `BROWSER` is the default way to specify which browser you prefer, regardless of which application it applies to.

- To choose the browser for a single session, set the `BROWSER` environment variable when running the jupyter process.

  `BROWSER=chromium-browser jupyter notebook` when you have `chromium-browser` when you prefer to use chromium-browser on PATH. Typical for Linux.

  `BROWSER=C:/Home/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe jupyter notebook` when you don't have the application on PATH. Typical for Windows.

  `BROWSER=<your browser> jupyter notebook` otherwise.
- To choose browser for your whole system, set the `BROWSER` environment variable globally.

Answer (score 3):

Find .../jupyter/runtime/nbserver-11596-open.html file, or whatever the file name is, you can find the file name when jupyter notebook starts, and associate it with Chorme worked for me.

Comment: For windows default path is 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime'

Answer (score 3):

Open anaconda prompt and type

```
jupyter notebook --generate-config
```

then go to "jupyter_notebook_config.py" path and add following line

```
c.NotebookApp.browser = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s'
```

Answer (score 3):

Is there any way to run jupyter on chrome in /tmp ?

something like that:

```
jupyter notebook --browser='google-chrome --user-data-dir=/tmp/'
```

Comment: `jupyter-lab --browser='firefox'` on macOS worked best for me after trying several other permutations.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to activate the line by removing the # comment indicator.

Answer (score 2):

After considerable thrashing about trying to launch a jupyter notebook in chrome from Anaconda in Win10 when chrome was not my default browser, I combined several of the suggestions above and, in the jupyter_notebook_config.py file under .jupyter in my home directory put in these lines in place of the default c.NotebookApp.browser line, and it finally worked!:

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.register('chrome', None, webbrowser.GenericBrowser(u'C:/PROGRA~2/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe'))
c.NotebookApp.browser = 'chrome'
```

Note the use of Unix-style directory separators (this is apparently a bug in webbrowser) and the use of DOS-style "PROGRA~2" --- both of these seem to be necessary.  Adding "%s" after "chrome.exe" seemed not to help.

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this on Windows 10, I had to do the following:

For a temporarily choose/specify a browser from the Anaconda Prompt CLI (note the order/type of quotes, they seem to be different to most other answers as those answers failed to work for me):

```
jupyter notebook --browser="'C:\Program Files (x86)\BraveSoftware\Brave-Browser\Application\brave.exe' %s"
```

To set it permanently, edit the jupyter_notebook_config.py file in your .jupyter folder. I'm not certain that you need to escape the backslashes (i.e. \ vs just ), but I used the following and it worked (again, note that the order/type of quotes is different):

```
c.NotebookApp.browser = '"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\BraveSoftware\\Brave-Browser\\Application\\brave.exe" %s'
```

Comment: Make sure you uncomment that line or it won't run!

Comment: Indeed this quotes sequence worked on Windows. Moreover, it works if typed directly in the Command Prompt. If placed in a .BAT file, then %s is to be replaced with %%s.

Answer (score 2):

Jupyterlab 3 [migrated from notebook server to plain jupyter server](https://jupyter-server.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operators/migrate-from-nbserver.html). To select the browser `jupyter lab` will open, put the config in `.jupyter/jupyter_server_config.py` and replace `NotebookApp` by `ServerApp`. For example:

```
c.ServerApp.browser = '/usr/bin/firefox -P notebook --new-window %s'
```

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft have setup Edge as a persistent virus on Windows.  Even if you set the default browser to Chrome in Settings, you still get edge when opening up Jupyter..  This is because Microsoft have set Edge as the default app for .htm and .html files.  In the settings for app defaults, find that one and change it to Chrome and you are all set..

Answer (score 1):

In my case, macOS 10.15.4 with anaconda 1.9.12, finally, I found an effective one as below:

c.NotebookApp.browser = u'/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome %s'

Answer (score 1):

if you didn't specify a browser for your jupyter notebook, maybe just changing the default browser of your operating system can solve your issue; like it did for me.
check default browser in window:
default apps: web browser

Answer (score 1):

Check your default browser's configurations, The default browser is where the Jupyter Notebook will open in.

on Windows, Simply change it doing:

1. Search in the start menu "Default apps", open it.
2. Under Web browser, select the browser currently listed, and then simply change it to your desired browser (where you want the Jupyter Notebook to open).

Comment: My default browser is Chrome, but the Jupyter notebook still opens in edge!

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps

1. Open Anaconda promt and write:

   jupyter notebook --generate-config
2. Go to that path and open with a text editor the .py file
3. In that file look for the line that constains the follow text:

   #c.NotebookApp.browser = ''
4. Before that line write the follow code

   import webbrowser
   webbrowser.register('chrome', None, webbrowser.GenericBrowser(u'C:/PROGRA~2/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe'))
5. Drop the symbol # in  the lines to set the browser, so it looks like:

   c.NotebookApp.browser = ''
6. Save the file, this makes Chrome as a default browser to launch jupyter notebook

Answer (score 0):

Use this command(windows cmd):

> jupyter notebook --browser NotebookApp.browser

It generates a link (localhost link), copy paste it in any browser that you need and use you notebook.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a way to **temporarily override the default browser** when launching jupyter lab. Therefore, all the other solutions based on generating a general config in the user home were not ideal.

Fortunately, it turns out that the same setting can be easily passed via the command line as well, which I think wasn't mentioned here yet:

```bash
jupyter lab --ServerApp.browser='google-chrome'
```

Tested with jupyter lab version 4.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

Open Jupyter Notebook and open the browser of preference (I am using Opera now). In the Notebook you will see:

[image: Jupyter Notebook lines]

Click any link and the you'd have Jupyter open in that browser.

Answer (score -2):

Easy steps:

1. Uninstall the current browser which notebook picks on launch.
2. Launch the notebook again, it will ask for browser: choose the required one and enable the clause which says : (something like) Always choose this application for this types of files.

It will work.
Install back you uninstalled browser.