# how to make jupyter able to launch MS. edge

Tags: jupyter-notebook, microsoft-edge

I want to use microsoftedge as the default browser jupyter would launch. But edge is always launched with opening my windows file path as web site input and jupyter failed to work of course. it's really confused.

Answer (score 4):

Which version of Microsoft Edge are you using? From [the Jupyter Notebook Browser Compatibility](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/notebook.html#browser-compatibility), we can see that:

*The Jupyter Notebook aims to support the latest versions of these browsers:*

- *Chrome*
- *Safari*
- *Firefox*

*Up to date versions of Opera and Edge may also work, but if they don’t, please use one of the supported browsers.*

The New Microsoft Edge is Chromium base, perhaps you need to install it, you could download it from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge).

Please refer to the following steps to set the default browser for Anaconda jupyter notebook

1. Launch Anaconda command Prompt
2. Type the command `jupyter notebook --generate-config`
3. Locate the generated configuration file in the path `C:\Users\XXXX\.jupyter\jupyter_notebook_config.py` and open it with notepad/any text editor.
4. Modify `#c.ServerApp.browser = ''` to `ServerApp.browser = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s'`
5. Save the file and close it

Next time executes the jupyter-notebook command, it will use the set browser.

Reference: [How to change the default browser used by jupyter notebook in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47772157/how-to-change-the-default-browser-used-by-jupyter-notebook-in-windows)

Comment: Thank you very much. My edge is not the  latest version. I will try  your advice.Many thanks!

Comment: It's odd that MS Edge is not yet supported. I pasted the jupyter notebook URL into Chrome and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

You can launch Jupyter on Edge by doing this:

1. Open **Anaconda Promt** and type this *jupyter notebook list*. It will show a group of tokens. Just copy one token and only the alphanumeric part.
2. Open Jupyter Notebook as normally. Copy the **local host address** from the adress bar of the default browser (for instance: Chrome).
3. Open Edge, copy the local host address. It will ask you a password or TOKEN.
4. Copy the TOKEN and voilà.

You can save the TOKEN in the password manager of Edge in order to get an easy access.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Microsoft Edge Versión 83.0.478.56 (Compilación oficial) (64 bits).

Well you can follow the same steps in the previous post, changing step four(4) like this:

1. Launch PowerShell or CMD
2. Type the command " jupyter notebook --generate-config "
3. Locate the generated configuration file in the path "C:\Users\XXXX.jupyter\jupyter_notebook_config.py" and open it with notepad/any text editor.
4. Modify #c.NotebookApp.browser to c.NotebookApp.browser = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft/Edge/Application/msedge.exe %s'
5. Save the file and close it
6. Stop the process in PowerShell or CMD (Ctrl + c)
7. Now, start the tool typing ***jupyter notebook*** in the PowerShell or CMD

Note: Don't forget uncomment (delete the hashtag symbol #) in step four(4)

Next time executes the jupyter-notebook command, it will use the set browser.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the configuration of `jupyter_notebook_config.py` has changed a bit, and now this line should be changed:

```
# c.ServerApp.browser = ''
```

Example replacement for Edge:

```
c.ServerApp.browser = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedge.exe'
```

Answer (score -1):

Use webbrowser to register Edge and use it:

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.register('edge', None, webbrowser.GenericBrowser('C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedge.exe'))
c.NotebookApp.browser = 'edge'
```

Comment: 'c' is not defined