# how to open jupyter notebook on desirable browser

Tags: python, browser, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

When I start **jupyter notebook**, it loads on **internet explorer**, but I want to open jupyter notebook on my desirable browser, please provide a **general solution** for all browsers. I am using windows 7.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the default browser used by jupyter notebook in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47772157/how-to-change-the-default-browser-used-by-jupyter-notebook-in-windows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to

> C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime

and then rightclick on any .html file and then go to change and then select any browser you want to an click on apply. Then run Jupyter notebook.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47772157/how-to-change-the-default-browser-used-by-jupyter-notebook-in-windows

Answer (score 0):

You can also copy the link from your Jupyter terminal and then paste it to your desirable browse.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47772157/how-to-change-the-default-browser-used-by-jupyter-notebook-in-windows