# jupyterlab looping in safari

Tags: macos, installation, anaconda, jupyter-lab

After I `pip install jupyterlab`, I can't open it since it gets stuck in an infinite loop in safari!. I want to change my browser to chrome and tried to do it through a solution offered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47772157/how-to-change-the-default-browser-used-by-jupyter-notebook-in-windows) but I can not find the `#c.NotebookApp.browser = ''` to change it.

Do you have any suggestion on how to solve this weird infinite problem in safari?

Answer (score 0):

I finally realized that the best work around this is to install a virtual environment and run jupyter lab there,

Simply run the followings:

```
1- pipenv install jupyterlab
2- pipenv shell
3- jupyter lab
```