# Does jupyter lab work within its own conda environment it was installed in?

Tags: anaconda, jupyter-lab

I have multiple conda environments on my PC created with Anaconda and I have installed jupyterlab in two of them. I used one environment for R programming and the other for Tensorflow with Python. I have noticed that whenever I open jupyter lab in either of the environments, it always starts off where I left it. That is, the last open notebooks are opened on start. Of course, this doesn't bother me too much, but it makes me think each jupyter lab installation isn't contained within its own environment.

For example, I have two environments. Say they're called `env_R` and `env_Python_TF`. I have installed jupyter lab in both environments.

I open Anaconda Powershell prompt and launch each environment using the following commands:

```
(base) PS $ conda activate env_R
(env_R)PS $ jupyter lab
```

Say I work on jupyter lab and once I'm done, I close the browser windows and then shut down the server using `CTRL+C` in Anaconda Powershell prompt. Now if I open up my second environment using:

```
(base) PS $ conda activate env_Python_TF
(env_Python_TF)PS $ jupyter lab
```

Now I see the same notebooks I used with `env_R` opened up when jupyter lab opens in my browser.

Aren't each jupyter lab installation contained within its own conda environments? If not, have I possibly made a mistake in my configuration?

Answer (score 0):

it should be within its own conda environment but Default root folder /location will remain same for jupyter notebook. You will need to change it using config file.

[Here is link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47772157/how-to-change-the-default-browser-used-by-jupyter-notebook-in-windows)

Comment: But can you explain the behaviour though? I'm finding it weird that it opens up the same notebooks regardless of the environment I activate jupyter lab in.