# how to open jupyter notebook in chrome instead of Internet explorer from anaconda Navigator?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I tried to open it in multiple ways but still not working. sometimes opening the jupyter notebook via manually typing jupyter.org in the search bar gives an error of binding.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the default browser used by jupyter notebook in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47772157/how-to-change-the-default-browser-used-by-jupyter-notebook-in-windows)

Answer (score 2):

You just need to configure your default browser as Google Chrome.

To do so,

1. Go to your start button and click on the search tab
2. Then key in "default", and click on "Default App"
3. Click on the web browser category and choose your preferred browser.

You can also refer to this if the above fails.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47793764/15299683

Answer (score 1):

Go to search and type Jupyter notebook and click on the application and there will be a black window that will pop up once it loads, kindly look for URLs that will appear once the window loads

URL might look like this= https:/local host.....

copy one of the URLs and then paste it in the chrome then you should be able to open jupyter notebook in chrome. Try this this will work

(OR)

Please scroll down to Web browser and Select Google Chrome. If promted, Click on OK else just close the settings tab and return to your command or anaconda prompt and type jupyter notebook as usual. A new jupyter notebook tab should open in Google Chrome now.