# Jupyter Lab hangs and catches up

Tags: python, jupyter, jupyter-lab

Thanks for the help, all. I'm sure this has been answered before, but it's difficult to search for a solution because of the many variations on similar symptoms.

I recently installed Jupyter Lab on my work laptop, and while I have no issues with the functionality itself, the ui regularly hangs while I'm trying to work/type. I'd say every fifteen seconds or so, the interface just stops responding for about 2-3 seconds. Anything I type in that period doesn't show up on screen, but then suddenly appears once the program is responding again. I'm getting no other signs of freezing, nonresponse, etc. besides a lack of onscreen response.

If this sounds familiar, thank you for any insight you can share on a fix.

Comment: You don't mention what version of JupyterLab you are using? On what type of system? Does it happen with anything you try? There's a thread on things that are reported to make the JupyterLab UI slow [here at the Jupyter Discourse Forum](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/cripplingly-slow-ui-am-i-the-only-one/5351/41?u=fomightez). That most recent one I directly link to details some of the specific cases that user noted where it seemed tied to the contextual help.

Comment: @Wayne, you're an absolute hero! That discussion noted that the Show Contextual Help tab, even if it's not the active tab, is always live and updating as you work elsewhere. Every time I made edits, it was playing catchup on that tab. I closed it out, and problem solved! I feel like I've had a huge splinter removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Full credit to Wayne in the comments. The "Show Contextual Help" tab continues to update behind the scenes as long as it's open, and this creates the intermittent stutters and lags. Close the Contextual Help tab and you're set!

Comment: How to close the contextual help tab? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you multiple possible solutions:

1. [Use a different browser if you can.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47772157/how-to-change-the-default-browser-used-by-jupyter-notebook-in-windows)
2. If you are using Anaconda, I suggest you update to the latest versions of Anaconda and Jupyter Notebook.
3. Maybe your pc is really slow but I highly doubt it.
4. If you're not using Anaconda, you should check it out :)

These are all the steps that I can think of from the get-go, hope this helps.