# a lot of lagging for a big file inside jupyter lab

Tags: jupyter-lab

I love jupyter lab. But for a big file ( 600KB), scrolling the file has a lot of lagging. I move my mouse to scroll down or up, but I have to wait for 5-20 seconds before the page starts to move. For the same file, if I open in VSC, it is very smooth without any lagging. so it is not related to my file issue. it is something to do with jupyter lab.

I am using latest jupyter lab version.

Any suggestion I can do to remove the lagging inside jupyter lab? Thanks

Comment: Or you using Chrome by any chance? See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/cripplingly-slow-scrolling-speeds-in-jupyter-lab-in-chrome/11031/7?u=fomightez). Or maybe you need to roll back your `jupyter_client` version? See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/cripplingly-slow-ui-am-i-the-only-one/5351/43?u=fomightez). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72291928/8508004) typing and experiencing lag was an issue and closing the Contextual Help tab helped.

Comment: Thank you Wayne. Yes I am using Chrome and I am using Microsoft Edge now and the lagging still exists. How to roll back jupyter_client version? and how to close contextual help tab? I don't see contextual tab opened in my file? Thanks

Comment: Hi Wayne, Yes I am using Microsoft Edge and I do found this lagging is improved a lot. Thank you so much for your help. It really make my days!

Comment: Hi Wayne, using Edge doesn't work again. It lags a lot. how to close the context help tab? I believe it is not enabled in my case. Thanks

Comment: You can enable showing 'Show Contextual Help' under the 'Help' menu in JupyterLab. Bringing it up and closing that tab/panel specifically should close it. Did you check the post I linked to in comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72291928/8508004) for further ideas? I don't know if anyone mentions Microsoft Edge.

Comment: Thanks Wayne, I did close the contextual help and I also did use Microsoft Edge as suggested from the link. None of them works. It still lags a lot, i mean, a lot. Thanks

Comment: lag too much, I am so frustrated with jupyter lab. I am thinking to use VSC with notebook file format.

Comment: I would encourage you to maybe post at [the post](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/cripplingly-slow-ui-am-i-the-only-one/5351/44?u=fomightez) in the Jupyter Discourse Forum, or start a new thread. Be specific and even share a minimal, mock notebook that causes it if you can. You may get better advice or things to try. Or possibly make the developers aware of something being missed. I don't have this issue; however, mainly use JupyterLab running via remote servers.

Comment: Thank you so much Wayne for your help, I appreciate it!