# How to change default browser for Jupyter Notebook opening via Anaconda in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: ubuntu, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, ubuntu-20.04, anaconda3

I am using different browsers for different purposes in Ubuntu. I would like for Jupyter Notebook to open in a different browser without having to change my default browser. There were a lot of examples showing how to do it for Windows, but they did not work in Ubuntu.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the default browser used by jupyter notebook in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47772157/how-to-change-the-default-browser-used-by-jupyter-notebook-in-windows)

Answer (score 1):

For this you need to create a Jupyter Notebook config file and set the notebook browser to your choice of browser. You may follow steps below to set the notebook to your default browser. Microsoft Edge is used as an example. You can use this method for any other browser.

**1. Create a Jupyter Notebook Config file**

For this first you need to make a Jupyter Notebook config file. You can do this using following command:

```
jupyter notebook --generate-config
```

Then open the config file. If you used the default location for the file it would be in:

```
./jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py
```

**2. Search for browser configuration**

Search for following word to change your Juypter Notebook launch browser.

```
c.NotebookApp.browser
```

**3. Find your browser path**
For this example I will be using microsoft edge

```
which microsoft-edge
```

The output will be:

```
/usr/bin/microsoft-edge
```

**4. Set the launch browser in Jupyter Notebook**

Paste the path from above and add %s in the end and remove #(uncomment) the line and save it.

```
c.NotebookApp.browser = '/usr/bin/microsoft-edge %s'
```

**5. Now you are done. Enjoy. Have a great day !!**