# jupyter notebook stop SSL error

Tags: python, docker, ssl, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm running a jupyter notebook inside an ubuntu 16.04 docker container, as a non-root user, with SSL configured via a `.pem` file. My issue is, I can't perform the `jupyter notebook stop $port` command to stop the running server.

I start the notebook by executing `sudo HOME=/home/seiji -u seiji jupyter notebook` to change the `HOME` environment variable (which is chown'd as seiji).

I can perform the usual `jupyter notebook list` command by running it as the user (`seiji`) and feeding in the `JUPYTER_RUNTIME_DIR` environment variable where jupyter looks for `json` files containing server info. For example: `sudo JUPYTER_RUNTIME_DIR=/jupyter/runtime -u seiji jupyter notebook list` correctly returns:
`https://localhost:8888/ :: /jupyter/notebooks` (I specify the runtime dir in the config file in the usual way).

My issue is, I can't figure out how to execute `jupyter notebook stop 8888` in a similar way. If I run it as is, it runs as root and tells me `There are no running servers`. If I run it as `user:seiji`, I run into SSL issues. As in:

```
> sudo JUPYTER_RUNTIME_DIR=/jupyter/runtime -u seiji jupyter notebook stop 8888
```

returns an error. It begins: `Shutting down server on port 8888 ...` but then prints the following:

**SSL Error on 10 ('::1', 8888, 0, 0): [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:645)**

My guess is that it tries a 'http' address to access the server instead of 'https', but I can't figure out how to change this.

I've also tried passing the environment variable `JUPYTER_CONFIG_DIR` which contains the config file listing the location of the `.pem` file with the line `c.NotebookApp.certfile = u'/jupyter/certs/mycert.pem'`. I've also tried explicitly feeding in the location of the cert when running from cmdline with `--certfile=[location]` but it seems this is ignored. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: For now I'm using `pkill jupyter`, which is the same as `kill $(pgrep jupyter)`, taken from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10162707/how-to-close-ipython-notebook-properly/32745046#32745046

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if your certificate cannot be verified by whichever SSL libraries are used by Jupyter (I think the details have changed a bit over time). This is common if there certificate is self-signed - the default certificate stores may not be able to verify your issuer. I currently do something like this with my Jupyter setup script:

`cat mycert.crt | openssl x509 -inform DER >> "$(python -c 'import certifi; print(certifi.where())')"`

I believe if you already have the certificate in PEM form then you only need:

`cat mycert.pem >> "$(python -c 'import certifi; print(certifi.where())')"`

and then start it like this:

`SSL_CERT_FILE=$(python -c 'import certifi; print(certifi.where())') jupyter notebook &`

and stop similarly:

`SSL_CERT_FILE=$(python -c 'import certifi; print(certifi.where())') jupyter notebook stop`

The reason I use the `certifi` location and environment variable is that `certifi` appears to be the most-favoured package, and the environment setting appears to be respected by other libraries (including `requests` and built-in SSL modules).

The reason to also start the server with this updated file is so that notebooks can themselves connect to the server (e.g. for introspection).