# VSCode Python Interactive Window - how to stop Jupyter server?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter

In Visual Studio Code, when I start the Python Interactive Window (by calling "Run Selection/Line in Python Interactive Window" command, for example), Jupyter server starts in the background. In that window, I can restart the kernel, but I can not find a way to stop the server. How can it be stopped? Simply closing the interactive window only disconnects from the server, but does not stop it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is no extra function build in VSCode. But you can manage it regularly from the terminal. You can stop it using `jupyter-notebook stop`.

Other ways are mentioned here as well: [How to close IPython Notebook properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10162707/how-to-close-ipython-notebook-properly)

Answer (score 3):

I have just started running notebooks in VSCode (Python) and wanted to stop a running cell, but couldn't find any way.

Just out of desperation I tried to change the running cell into a markdown cell and back to a code cell.  That seemed to halt the process despite being hilariously inelegant.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: "hilariously inelegant." That's now going to be the principle I strive towards! But joking aside: This did seem to solve a similar issue for me, where I could "recover" a cell that somehow disconnected from the Kernel ( `Failed to interrupt the Kernel. No kernel associated with the notebook. View Jupyter log for further details.`) But it's not really consistent and I don't have a clue what it does exactly. So yea, hilariously inelegant.

Answer (score 1):

Finding the process in the task manager was the only option that worked for me.

If you are using the "Default" VSCode jupyter option running `jupyter-notebook stop` won't work. This is a [known bug](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/4369) in vscode, but they closed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that

- Jupyter Lab
- Jupyter Notebook

and the kernel that they (they are 'servers') give you to run each Notebook
are different things.

---

To stop a running Jupyter Notebook / Lab server, you can use the following command:

```
jupyter notebook stop
jupyter lab stop
```

This command will stop the Jupyter notebook server running on the default port (8888).

If your server is running on a different port, you need to specify it:

```
jupyter notebook stop {port_number}
jupyter lab stop {port_number}
```

Stopping the server will stop all the running kernels.

---

Unfortunately, there's no built-in command line interface for listing running Jupyter kernels or stopping a specific kernel. You can only do this through the Jupyter notebook or Jupyter Lab interface.

When you hover over a kernel, an `x` will appear for you to close it manually. [Image is JupyterLab]

[image]