# how to stop jupyter-dash from running in vscode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyterdash

I am  using jupyter-dash in VSCode. I have a big iteration. sometime I'd like to stop running.

I tried few options in the below link and they never work.

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58230077/vscode-python-interactive-window-how-to-stop-jupyter-server#:~:text=You%20can%20stop%20it%20using%20jupyter%2Dnotebook%20stop%20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58230077/vscode-python-interactive-window-how-to-stop-jupyter-server#:%7E:text=You%20can%20stop%20it%20using%20jupyter%2Dnotebook%20stop%20).

[How to close IPython Notebook properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10162707/how-to-close-ipython-notebook-properly)

If I use below with port number like this:

```
jupyter-notebook stop 8064

error:
[NbserverStopApp] WARNING | Config option `kernel_spec_manager_class` not recognized by `NbserverStopApp`.
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [problem](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/4369) you pasted, jupyter cannot guarantee interruption, so the best solution is to restart jupyter manually by clicking **Reastart** or **Reload VsCode**.

[image]

[image]